# Why is object of type 'closure' is not subsettable?

Tags: r

I have tried the code two months ago and it worked back then, but now it won't work.

This is the code:

```
summary(example[, 1:3] )
```

> error in example[, 1:3] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

I have several other codes with `[]` and they give the same error.

Comment: It'll help if you discuss 1) what changed from two months ago to now? 2) provide a small reproducible example

Comment: Hi CPak, Thank you very much, but figured my problem was that my definition of "example" was not right.

Answer (score 2):

`example` was likely defined as a function instead of a summarize-able object like a numeric vector.

```
example <- function(a) { print(a) }
class(example)
example[1]
```

yields

> [1] "function"
>
> Error in example[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

whereas

```
example <- 1:3
class(example)
example[1]
```

yields

> [1] "numeric"
>
> [1] 1